# default value of a select in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-cloud-firestore

I have a select to choose a category when adding an item to a crud with react (with firestore). It works fine if I select a value other than the default value but if I leave the default value, without changing it, I don't get the value of the category. It must be because for the useState to take the value of the select, the onchange event must be fired, and if the default value is left, the onchange event is not fired. Can you think of any way to solve this? This is the complete code:

```
import React from 'react';
//import {app} from './firebase'
import {db} from './firebase'

import {
  getFirestore,
  collection,
  getDocs,
  onSnapshot,
  addDoc,
  deleteDoc,
  doc,
  getDoc,
  updateDoc
}from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.8.1/firebase-firestore.js";

  function App() {

    const [tareas, setTareas] = React.useState([])
    const [tarea, setTarea] = React.useState('')
    const [modoEdicion, setModoEdicion] = React.useState(false)
    const [id, setId] = React.useState('')
    const [categorias, setCategorias] = React.useState([])
    const [categoria, setCategoria] = React.useState([])

  React.useEffect(() => {

    const obtenerDatos = async () => {

      try {


        const querySnapshot = await getDocs(collection(db, "Articulos"));
        querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
       
        });
        const arrayData = querySnapshot.docs.map(doc => ({ id: doc.id,titulo:doc.data().titulo ,contenido:doc.data().contenido}))
        setTareas(arrayData)
       
        
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)}
    }
  
    const obtenerCategorias = async () => {

      try {


        const querySnapshot = await getDocs(collection(db, "Categorias"));
        querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
       
        });
        const arrayData = querySnapshot.docs.map(doc => ({ id: doc.id,nombre:doc.data().nombre}))
        setCategorias(arrayData)
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
      }
      
    }

    obtenerDatos()
    obtenerCategorias()

  }, [])

  const agregar = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()

    if(!tarea.trim()){
      console.log('está vacio')
      return
    }

    try {

      const nuevaTarea = {
        titulo: "tarea",
        contenido: "categoria"
      }
      const docRef = await addDoc(collection(db, "Articulos"), {titulo:tarea,contenido:categoria});

      setTareas([
        ...tareas,
        {titulo:tarea,contenido:categoria, id: docRef.id}

      ])

      setTarea('')
      
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error)
    }


  }

  const eliminar = async (id) => {
    try {
      

      const articleToDelete = doc(db,`Articulos/${id}`)
      deleteDoc(articleToDelete)

      const arrayFiltrado = tareas.filter(item => item.id !== id)
      setTareas(arrayFiltrado)

    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error)
    }
  }

  const activarEdicion = (item) => {
    setModoEdicion(true)
    setTarea(item.name)
    setId(item.id)
  }

  const handleUpdate = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    const taskDocRef = doc(db, 'Articulos', id)
    try{
      await updateDoc(taskDocRef, {
        titulo: tarea,
        contenido: "my content"
      })
    
      const querySnapshot = await getDocs(collection(db, "Articulos"));
        querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
          
       
        });
        const arrayData = querySnapshot.docs.map(doc => ({ id: doc.id,titulo:doc.data().titulo }))
        setTareas(arrayData)

      setModoEdicion(false)
      setTarea('')
      setId('')

    } catch (err) {
      alert(err)
    }    
  }

  
  //const CuadroTexto = ({ titulo }) => <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" value={titulo}/>


  return (
    <div className="container mt-3">
      <div className="row">
        <div className="col-md-6">
          <h3>Lista de tareas</h3>
          <table>

            {
              tareas.map(item => (
                
                  <tr>
                    
                  <td>{item.titulo}</td>
                  <td>{item.contenido}</td>
                  <td>
                  <button 
                    className="btn btn-danger btn-sm float-right"
                    onClick={() => eliminar(item.id)}
                  >                
                    Eliminar
                  </button>
                  </td>
                  <td>
                  <button 
                    className="btn btn-warning btn-sm float-right mr-2"
                    onClick={() => activarEdicion(item)}
                  >
                    Editar
                  </button>
                  </td>
                
                  </tr>
                
              ))
            }

          </table>
        </div>
        <div className="col-md-6">
          <h3>
            {
              modoEdicion ? 'Editar Tarea' : 'Agregar Tarea'
            }
          </h3>
          <form onSubmit={modoEdicion ? handleUpdate : agregar}>
            <input 
              type="text"
              placeholder="Ingrese tarea"
              className="form-control mb-2"
              onChange={e => setTarea(e.target.value)}
              value={tarea}
            />
            <select onChange={c => setCategoria(c.target.value)} value={categoria}>
                    {
                     
                    categorias.map(item2 => (
                    <option value={item2.nombre}>{item2.nombre}</option>
                    ))
                    }
            </select>
            <button 
              className={
                modoEdicion ? 'btn btn-warning btn-block' : 'btn btn-dark btn-block'
              }
              type="submit"
            >
              {
                modoEdicion ? 'Editar' : 'Agregar'
              }
            </button>
            
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: You can just set a default value for your categoria here `const [categorias, setCategorias] = React.useState([])
const [categoria, setCategoria] = React.useState([])
`, so if the input is not changed it will have the original value

Comment: When are you populating the `categorias` state? You can simply set `categoria` at the same time to be the appropriate value from the array, ie. `useEffect(() => {const categoriasData = getData(); setCategorias(categoriasData); setCategoria(categoriasData[0].nombre); }, []);`

Comment: i didn't managed to solve the problem. I've edited the post and added the entired code to see if you can give me a more concrete answer Thank you!